# Given Least Squares of a set, compute Least Square of the set excluding a single element

Tags: least-squares, dynamic-programming, regression-analysis, linear-regression

I am trying to figure out how to implement a cyclic running Regression Line computing algorithm using Least Squares for streaming time series data in the most efficient way. In other words, having $LS(s)$ im looking for a way to compute $LS(s)$ after adding an element to s and removing the kth oldest element from it.

Given a set $s$ of $x,y$ samples I was thinking maybe it is possible to compute $LS(s\bigcup\{a\})$ (for some new sample $a$) and $LS(s-\{a\})$ (for some sample $a$ in $s$, specifically the oldest sample) given $LS(s)$, is there a known solution to this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. When you are varying the sample, what are you dropping? Observations or variables? If variables, maybe you are looking at a problem how to calculate one OLS coefficient without calculating the other. See whuber's answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46151/how-to-derive-the-least-square-estimator-for-multiple-linear-regression

Comment: in every iteration i want to add a new sample and remove the k'th oldest one, example of such a running algorithm is the onlione algorithm that calculates variance here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance I want the same only for Least squares instead of variance, and with the ability to remove the kth oldest element from the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that I properly understand.*

If you use normal equations for the regression $y=a+bx$, $a$ and $b$ are given solving the  equations $$S_y=n a+b S_x$$ $$S_{xy}=a S_x+b S_{xx}$$ Now, you want to add point $n+1$ and remove point $1$ from the regression set. So, the equations are now $$S'_y=n a'+b' S'_x$$ $$S'_{xy}=a' S'_x+b' S'_{xx}$$Computing the terms we have   $$S'_y=S_y+y_{n+1}-y_1$$ $$S'_x=S_x+x_{n+1}-x_1$$ $$S'_{xy}=S_{xy}+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-x_1y_1$$ $$S'_{xx}=S_{xx}+x_{n+1}^2-x_1^2$$ which make the updating process quite simple.

For sure, when this is done, do not forget to replace make the update $S=S'$ and to shift the indices $k=k-1$ to be ready for the next step.

Comment: This seem to work! Thank you!

Comment: @OfekRon. You are very welcome ! This was a sketch of the idea. You can make it more general preserving all $(x_i,y_)$ considering that, at a given time, you have $M$ data points and that you perform the regression using the last $n$ of them.

Comment: What if $x$ gets bigger while $x_i-x_{i-1}$ is constant (1 in my case)?, since im only intrested on the regression line for last $n$ items, is it possible to reuse  $x_0$ to $x_n$ (0 to n in my case) as the x's? if it is, how would you change your iteration move?

Comment: How do you apply weightings on this?

Comment: @OfekRon. Same idea, for sure if the weights are independent from eachother. Just write again the normal equations with weights and proceed the same way.

Comment: can you edit the answer with the formulas with weights? you can also answer me here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153699/how-to-apply-weightings-to-least-squares-slope-formula